# Cómo borro el último git add . que hice?

Tags: git

Tengo dos ramas, la master y rama-dos, el problema es que en la master generé el git ignore, donde puse el node modules, pero en la rama-dos no. Cuando quise agregar algunos cambios a la rama-dos utilicé el git add . y se me subieron todos los archivos de node modules que NO QUERIA SUBIR. Todavía no hice commit, cómo puedo volver atrás para quitar la carpeta node modules y poder situarla en un gitignore? muchas gracias

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Al ser mi último commit resolví con git reset --hard HEAD~1 y funcionó pero me borró la carpeta de node modules. Muchas gracias

Comment: Es que la solución dada por @eftshift0 es lo correcto. `git reset node_modules` (o su equivalente `git reset --mixed node_modules`) borra `node_modules` del INDEX, pero no lo toca en tu WORKING TREE. Esta es la acción a tomar para quitar del INDEX algo que entró con el `git add` pero no debería haber entrado. `git reset --hard HEAD~1` te quitó del INDEX y del WORKING TREE todo lo que habías hecho desde HEAD~1. A veces, este comportamiento puede causarte dolores de cabeza.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer:

```
git reset .
```

Que va a limpiar el index para que empieces a agregar de nuevo.

O tambien

```
git reset item1
git reset item2
```

para sacar ítemes específicos del index.

Comment: Claro, el problema es que tengo mucha info en el index que no quiero perder ni modificar, sólo quiero quitar la carpeta de node modules de git para poder pasarla a un git ignore

Comment: Entiendo. Acabo de hacer un ajuste a la respuesta que espero que te funcione.

Comment: si solo quieres quitar la carperta node modules solo has un git rm -rf node_modules/ haces un commit y push y listo

Comment: Atención: ese comando que indica @CristianMendoza no solo va a borrar el directorio _del index_ sino que lo va a borrar del árbol de trabajo también.

Comment: si pero eso lo puede volver a instalar y lo añades en .gitignore o puedes hacer el reverse del commit que hiciste

Comment: Yo te entiendo perfectamente pero otras personas podrían no entenderlo y hacer lo que dices sin pensar (y no necesariamente con un directorio como `node_modules` que se resetea con `npm install` o algo así... podría ser otro directorio que no se pueda recuperar.... _especialmente_ porque según indica la OP, no ha hecho commit).

Comment: Gracias! He solucionado, como fue mi último commit utlicé git reset --hard HEAD~1